# postmessage parent to child page with an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I am trying to send some data from a parent html page to a child.html via an iframe.

The parent HTML with the iframe

```
<!-- parent.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Parent Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Parent Page</h1>

  <iframe id="myIframe" src="child.html" width="400" height="300"></iframe>

  <script>

  // Reference to the iframe element
const iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

// Data to be sent to the iframe
const dataToSend = {
  message: 'Hello from parent!',
  someValue: 42
};

// Send the data to the iframe
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(dataToSend, '*');


  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The child HTML with the eventlistener

```
<!-- child.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Child Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Child</h1>

  <script>
// Listen for messages from the parent window
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // Ensure the message is from a trusted origin
  if (event.origin === '*') {
    // Access the data sent from the parent window
    const receivedData = event.data;

    // Do something with the data
    console.log(receivedData.message);
    console.log(receivedData.someValue);
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But i do not see any response. Do you see what is going wrong?

[text](https://rossewij.nl/parent.html)

I do not get any response in the iframe

Comment: Probably a timing issue ...? You are not waiting for the iframe content to load before you fire off your message - so my guess would be, that `window.addEventListener('message',` has not even executed yet at that point. So your message sends fine, only there hasn't been anything instructed to actually listen for it at the receiving end so far.

Comment: Hi Arjan and welcome to SO. I think @CBroe is correct in that the timing is correct. Executing `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(dataToSend, '*');` in the browser console will show that a message has been sent, though I don't think `event.origin` will be `'*'`, but will be the URI of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant of the ways to handle this kind of scenario, but since you're using iframe i think is the only option available to you.

To make it work i just added some code to the script.

Parent.html

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
console.log('Im the parent, im loading my scripts')

// Create a listener handler for the child iframe
// when the child is ready to receive messages, 
// parent will send data to child
const handleMessage = (event) => {
  if (event.source === iframe.contentWindow) {
    if (event.data === 'imListening') {
      console.log('Im the parent and child is ready to receive messages. i will send a message to child now!')
      const dataToSend = {
        message: 'Hello from parent!',
        someValue: 42
      };
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(dataToSend, '*');
    }
  }
};

// Add event listener for the message event
window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
```

And child.html

```
 // create a listener when child page fully loaded and emit a message to parent
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log('Im the child and ready to receive messages from parent!')
    window.parent.postMessage('imListening', '*');
  })

  // listen for messages from parent
  window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log("Im the child and i've received this from parent: " + event.data.message);
  });
```

I'm gonna explain what i did: First of all i'm putting a couple of listeners inside the child.html:

- one listener will handle the full load of the child page and will emit an event to the parent where it says "i'm ready to receive messages"
- the second listener will wait for the parent to send messages to child and handle them

in the parent i've put also a listener that will handle the message from the child when the it is ready to listen.

so: parents load -> child loads -> child is ready -> child notifies the parent that is ready -> parent receives the ready from child -> parent sends data to child -> child prints data from parent

hope it helps.